# Conditions for equivalence of $A$-modules, given equivalence of $B$-modules for $B$ a subalgebra of $A$.

Tags: representation-theory, modules

Pardon me if my terminology is messed up and I must admit that the following question is rather general, but here goes:

> Let $A$ be an algebra and $B$ a proper subalgebra of $A$. Suppose that, as $B$-modules, $V$ and $W$ are $B$-isomorphic. Under what conditions (on $V, W$ or $A, B$) can we say that $V$ and $W$ are $A$-isomorphic?

The particular situation I am looking at is that I am given two representations of the braid group, $B_n$ and I know how to show that they are $B_{n-1}$-isomorphic, but I would like to conclude that they are $B_n$-isomorphic.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, one easy example where this _doesn't_ happen is when $A = \mathbb{C}$, $B = \mathbb{Q}$, $V = \mathbb{C}^n$, $W = \mathbb{C}^m$, $n \ne m$...

Comment: @ Zhen Lin Why $\mathbb{C}^n$  and $\mathbb{C}^m$ are $\mathbb{Q}$-isomorphic?